# Multiple Facebook Page Id's for the same page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using graph API to link user's Facebook pages in our application to partner with users to submit content posted on their pages. But lately, I've found a user having two page Ids for the same page.

sample links with pageId's:
https://www.facebook.com/508964xxxxxxx
https://www.facebook.com/9874368xxxxxx

The user has authenticated and linked his channel, when he linked his channel I've captured one page Id, but when we look at the urls of videos he posted on his page
sample: https://www.facebook.com/9874368xxxxx/videos/3636691xxxxxx/ are having a different page Id, first path param in the sample url is the page Id and the second is videoId.

could someone help me understand the situation here, why we have two different page Id's for the same page and what can I do to use the same Id for both linking the page and submitting the content?

FYI: we are using only one Facebook app, I don't think we have the app scoped Ids here, what we have is the actual page Id

Here are the graph apis:

To get the list of all pages of a Facebook account with a user access token : https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts

To get page information with page access token and page Id which we receive from the above response:
[https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}?fields=fan_count,link,name,picture](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bpage-id%7D?fields=fan_count,link,name,picture)

Comment: Sounds to me as if they might have simply _shared_ a video from a different page, instead of actually uploading one themself?

Comment: here are the links, both refer to the same page. https://www.facebook.com/101426851637066, https://www.facebook.com/100058143367499

Comment: Okay, that's really unusual. Was this page merged with a second one at some point maybe? When you query `/me/accounts` for the user, do you get both of those IDs back from there as well? Or is it just when querying the videos of page A, you get video IDs that refer to page B?